# How to allow selection via icon on dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, fuelux

I'm using fuelux with bootstrap to create some nice selections via drop downs.

In the drop down I'm placing icons via font-awesome. I've managed to get the icons to render fine and when selected, the icon is included as selected.

My problem is when I click on an icon in an activated drop down. The selection occurs but is set to nothing. I have to click on either the text or white space around the icon on the dropdown list.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is a JS Fiddle that demonstrates the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/metalskin/xye7zj3n/

The code in the jsfiddle is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="title">Title</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input 
                      id="title" 
                      name="title" 
                      type="text" 
                      placeholder="Enter the title" 
                      class="form-control input-md"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="icon">Icon</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 fuelux">
                    <div 
                      class="btn-group selectlist" 
                      data-initialize="selectlist" 
                      id="iconSelectlist">
                        <button 
                          class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
                          data-toggle="dropdown" 
                          type="button">
                          <span class="selected-label">
                              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i></a>
                          </span>
                          <span class="caret"></span>
                          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li data-value="a">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Users</a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-value="b">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-lg"></i> Camera</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <input 
                          class="hidden hidden-field" 
                          name="mySelectlist" 
                          readonly="readonly" 
                          aria-hidden="true" 
                          type="text"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-fluid {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.row {
    margin: auto
}
.row.no-pad {
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0;
}
.row.no-pad >[class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
ul.dropdown-menu-form {
    color: black;
}
.selected-label {
    color: #555;
}
.dropdown-toggle {
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.dropdown-toggle:focus {
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.dropdown-toggle:hover {
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.caret {
    color: #333;
}
```

External resources:

```
http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/assets/vendor/fuelux/dist/css/fuelux.css
http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
http://www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.0.2/js/fuelux.min.js
```

DTD:

```
HTML 5
```

Normalised CSS:

```
true
```

Body Tag:

```
<body class="fuelux">
```

And jQuery 2.x (edge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. Previously only the `<a>` was allowed as a clickable child element. Icon support was a recent addition. Please see issue and pull request, [Selectlist is empty when icon is clicked instead of text label](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/681) This should be merged into master with release 3.0.3.

Comment: Ahh thank you. I suspected it was a defect as further testing demonstrated that if I used 3.0.0 it allowed selection of the icon, just didn't show the icon in the selection result. Was going to investigate further today and see if it was a defect. :-)